# CSS - I would like to implement round (inverse) corner for texts

Tags: css, text, background, rounded-corners, border-radius

I often see the design with the rounded corners. But I haven't seen a live version yet. I would like to implement this myself but except before/after with inverse-border-radius I have no idea for the implementation.

Especially for headings I would be interested in this, where this adjusts automatically and 2 line headings are no problem.  As seen with the button, just like to have a text paragraph.

Does anyone have an approach for this. Would be happy about help

[image]

Comment: "but except before/after with inverse-border-radius" I have no idea what this means, maybe it would be clearer with a simple example of what you want (there are many different round corners in the picture). A reproducible example of what you have done and in which way it differs from what you want would be good too

Comment: _"where this adjusts automatically"_ - to / regarding _what_? _"and 2 line headings are no problem."_ - and in which way _are_ they a problem with what you tried?

Comment: Please describe what is meant by 'inverse' here. All I can see in the picture are 'ordinary' rounded borders.

Answer (score 1):

there is no such thing as "negative border radius". If you know what background you will be using, you can mask it with some before/after elements:

```css
body{
background: #aaa;
padding: 60px;
}
.big{
background: #fff;
padding: 100px;
border-radius: 10px;
position: relative;
}
.small{
position:absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
padding: 20px;
border-radius: 10px;
background: #888;
outline: 10px solid #aaa;
}
.small:before{
content: "";
position:absolute;
top: 0;
right: -20px;
width: 20px;
height: 10px;
background: radial-gradient(circle at 100% 100%, transparent 10px, #aaa 10px);
}
.small:after{
content: "";
position:absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: -20px;
width: 10px;
height: 20px;
background: radial-gradient(circle at 100% 100%, transparent 10px, #aaa 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="big">

<div class="small">Cutted out</div>
Main content with image
</div>
```

Comment: @BenjaminSeifert This is the comment area. Do not ask new questions here. Open a new question instead.